# Darknet attribute error on Windows. Something wrong with the DLL?

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

I am attempting to run a python file, darknet_video.py (or any python file) on Windows 10.

While running on linux I have had no problems using the .SO in exactly the same way. However, I am forced to have to port this to Windows and use the DLL.

I have compiled yolo_cpp_dll.sln with Visual Studio 17. No errors. On the command line, I can invoke darknet with, say,

```
./darknet.exe detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights -thresh 0.25
```

The above works.

What does not work is the following:

```
python.exe darknet_video.py --data_file cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg/yolov3.weights ..
```

With the above I get the following

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "darknet_video.py", line 119, in 
> network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network(
> AttributeError: module 'darknet' has no attribute 'load_network'

This type of error is the same no matter what kind of a python file I use.

I am certainly not an expert in using Windows DLLs but if I had to guess I would say that somehow the DLL was compiled in such a way that it can not understand calls such as "load_network" or any other type of call that is made.

How to proceed?
Thank You
Tom

Comment: So if you create a python file that contains: `print("hello world")`, you can't run it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Kind of frustrated here. 
Yes, simple print.py file containing "print ("Hello, Python!)"
Gives result
"Hello, Python!"

Comment: Did you write the darknet python file? It seems like the issue is with load_network

Comment: No, I did not write the darknet_video.py. I downloaded it from AlexeyAB github. I have tried a couple of variations, nothing works.
However, all of this does work under linux, using the .so.  I'm sure it has something to do with the dll and how it is compiled. I did a fresh compile of the dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled yolo_cpp_dll.sln correctly you
would get yolo_cpp_dll.dll then in darknet.py
change `lib= CDLL('whatever')` to
`lib = CDLL("yolo_cpp_dll.dll", RTLD_GLOBAL).`